# JSON goes into a dictionary nicely, but objectForKey errors

Tags: ios, json, rest, ios5

I have a RESTful API serving JSON. I'm calling it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                        kProjectList];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

Then I have my fetchedData method:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];
    //NSArray *projects = [json objectForKey:@"name"]; //2

    NSLog(@"name: %@", json); //3
}
```

If I uncomment //NSArray line I get `-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d81720`

With it commented out, my dictionary logs:

```
(
        {
        "created_at" = "2012-04-04T01:46:51Z";
        description = "First Project Created";
        id = 1;
        name = "Test 1";
        "updated_at" = "2012-04-04T01:46:51Z";
    },
        {
        "created_at" = "2012-04-04T01:47:23Z";
        description = "Second Project Created";
        id = 2;
        name = "Test 2";
        "updated_at" = "2012-04-04T01:47:23Z";
    }
)
```

Comment: I have read in other similar problems that where I have NSArray, I should have NSDictionary. Making this change gives me the exact same error (different instance 0x####### obviously).

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary of arrays. Instead of objectForKey, use objectAtIndex and assign to a dictionary. Do this:

```
NSDictionary *projects = [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change NSDictionary* json to an NSArray and then used your above code and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.